# Записать данное условие Pascal на С++

Tags: c++, pascal

Решаю задачку из ЕГЭ. Есть проблема, я не могу нормально записать условие, чтобы выводило данную таблицу истинности.

**Код прикладываю:**

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x,y,z,w;

  for (x = 0; x <= 1; x++)
     for (y = 0; y <= 1; y++)
        for (z = 0; z <= 1; z++)
            for (w = 0; w <= 1; w++)
                if(((x && (~y)) || (y^z) || (~w)) == 0)
                {
                    cout << x << w << z << y << endl;
                }

  return 0;

}
```

В чем проблема? В паскале я спокойно смог написать условие с помощью or,and,xor,not
А в C++ "паскальсковский" not отсутствует?

Помогите с данной проблемой и как надо записать данное условие?

**Задачка:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему же отсутствует? `!x`

Comment: @Harry не подходит, выводит

0100 0111 1111

Comment: @Harry Да и я имею ввиду логику работы not как в Паскале.

Comment: Вы смешали в одном выражении побитовые операции и логические. Вам все-же что нужно? Работа с логическими значениями или побитовые операции?

Comment: Если логические, и я Вас правильно понял, то должно получиться так: `(! ((x && (!y)) || (y != z) || (!w)))` Проверка на равенство нулю не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же в С++ - никаких `int`, только `bool`:

```
bool F(bool X, bool Y, bool Z, bool W)
{
    return (X && !Y) || (Y == Z) || !W;
}
```